# Skype link in Email Signature does not work on gmail client

Tags: hyperlink, gmail, skype

I have an email signature in which all the links work fine in every mail client except the skype one:

```
<span>Skype:</span> <span><a href="skype:jared.rake?add">Jared.Rake</a></span>
```

The link works as intended (launches the skype client) on all mail clients except gmail. Any idea why this is so?

- I have the skype client installed on my system.
- When you inspect the span tag(the one that contains the name, I can see the link (`<a>`) tag, but I cannot see the `href` attribute.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do other links work in the signature?

Answer (score 17):

I already see proper answer but want to make it more clear:
You can build simple "http://" link that leads to your link "skype:profile_name?add".  And this http:// link will work great in any mail signature. Even in GMail.

But not all shortners will work properly. I tested it with http://is.gd/ and it works great!

So you need to:

1. Go to http://is.gd/
2. shorten your link skype:jared.rake?add and get http:// link
3. use this http:// link in email signature
4. profit! :)

Comment: Gmail is blocking is.gd links now (started a couple of weeks ago)

Comment: Thank you for this update. I would like to fix this instruction with link on proper service. Do you know any other shortner supporting URL like "skype:smthg"?

Comment: I'm not aware of which URL shorteners support skype URLs and which do not. But I expect that any similar service is likely to get abused by spammers/scammers (in spite of efforts to prevent that) and consequently Gmail may decide to block them. Btw, I've seen some signs that Gmail has stopped blocking is.gd in the meantime, but after getting burned once, I'd rather not risk it again. My current suggestion would be to set up some redirecting links on a [sub]domain that you own.

Comment: Correction: Gmail is still blocking is.gd, but apparently not always. I haven't figured out the logic behind.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely it is because you are not using a real url as your href value. If it works on everything except Gmail, then it is probably a support issue in Gmail that is causing the problems. Unless there is a URL based value you could use instead, you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail strips out URLs that look like skype:jared.rake?add

So... make a tinyURL pointing to your Skype url, and link to the tinyURL instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you want to rebrand your skype link you can use a subdomain that redirects to your is.gd link to keep your links branded. I created a post about this here: http://meerkat.link/skype-in-gmail-sig-using-isgd

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, in case, you own a domain name (you have a blog or personal website), is to create a PHP file containing the following lines of code:

```
header("Location: skype:SKYPE_ID?call");
exit();
```

Just replace **SKYPE_ID** with your ID and attach the URL of the file to your email signature. Thus, you are in total control of the link.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol skype does not work on some browsers (or PC that does not have skype installed.) The best option is to add a normal link and direct it to the Skype call page. I got this information from the [Add Skype link to email signature](https://www.bybrand.io/docs/en/article/add-skype-chat-link/).

See the example below:

```
https://join.skype.com/invite/iOBDAq6GG
```

Don't forget to set the color of the link with **style** option. Because [Gmail changes the default color to blue](https://www.bybrand.io/blog/preventing-gmail-change-color-of-phone-email-website/) in the phone, email, and website texts.

In your example change to or similar:

```
<span style="color:#333;"><a style="color:#333;" href="https://join.skype.com/iOBDAq6GG">Jared.Rake</a></span>
```